# Hide image when scrolling

Tags: android, android-fragments

For fragments I created one custom class to access but now I want hide the image instead of toolbar using eclipse.

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    case 1:
        fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    case 2:
        fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        break;
    }

    SamplFragment defaultFragment = SamplFragment.newInstance(position, offerListData);
    return defaultFragment;
}
```